# dimension error for plotting command in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a graph which is a vertical cross-section of wind speed data, so that on the x-axis there is the latitudinal coordinates and the y-axis has the vertical levels.

I have calculated a wind speed which has a latitudinal component and a vertical. When I print the shape of it gives (37,81), I know that there are 37 levels in this data so I assume that that means that the 37 is the vertical component and the 81 is the latitudinal component. The problem that I am having however is that I want this variable to have the 81 and 37 the other way around so that the 37 is y-axis. Is there a way to swap the two components of this variable?

this is  the code that I have done so far:

```
    # read tos
f = Dataset('data/era5_u_wind_vertical_levels_1979_2018_DJF.nc', mode='r')
lons = f.variables['longitude'][0]
lats = f.variables['latitude'][:]
levs = f.variables['level'][:]
field_u = f.variables['u'][0,:,:,0]
field_uu = f.variables['u'].units
f.close()

f = Dataset('data/era5_v_wind_vertical_levels_1979_2018_DJF.nc', mode='r')
#lons = f.variables['longitude'][:]
#lats = f.variables['latitude'][:]
field_v = f.variables['v'][0,:,:,0]
field_vv = f.variables['v'].units
f.close()

print np.shape(field_u), np.shape(field_v)
print lons

#steps = 50
#lonsnew = np.linspace(lon0, lon1, steps)
#latsnew = np.linspace(lat0, lat1, steps)

# compute absolute windspeed
wspd = np.sqrt(np.square(field_v) + np.square(field_u))
print wspd.shape

# test
print np.min(wspd), np.max(wspd)
print lats.shape, levs.shape, wspd.shape

#create lat/levs grid
[lats, levs] = np.meshgrid(levs, lats)
print lats.shape, levs.shape, wspd.shape

# define countour levels and plot filled contours
levels = np.arange(0, 21, 1)
cmap = plt.cm.gist_rainbow_r
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(levels, cmap.N)

# actual plotting command
myplot = m.pcolormesh(lats, levs, wspd, norm=norm, cmap=cmap)
```

and the error that I get:
TypeError: Dimensions of C (37, 81) are incompatible with X (37) and/or Y (81); see help(pcolormesh)

Comment: Make sure to include your code while asking a question.

Comment: x[0], x[1] = x[1], x[0]... assuming you are using a list

Comment: @koto `tuple` object does not support item assignment, this will only work for a list

Comment: @Alex thanks for the hint, I forgot about that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your variable is a tuple:

```
speed = (37,81)
speed_swap = speed[1], speed[0]
speed_swap
# (81, 37)
```